Audio outputs low w/ introduced high pitched whining
I'm not much of an audio guy, nor do I know really any of the proper terms, so apologies if something doesn't make an sense.
I've had this computer set-up for a really long time. Around a year ago I got complaints from friends in discord that I was way too quiet, and that they were having problems hearing me at 200%. I checked the level of my mic in Windows, and sure enough it was WAY too low, around 54. After turning it up I realized that there was quite a bit of introduced background noise coming from something. For the last year I've been playing a game of balancing the microphone level in Windows, NVIDIA broadcast (mainly just on max settings), and my mixer. But I'd like to solve the issue.
I originally thought the issue was being caused by an installation (and improper uninstallation) of voice mod, so I imagined if I reinstalled windows after clearing the drive I had it installed to the problem would be solved. It wasn't. It's entirely possible that the one drive I didn't purge is the one I installed voicemod to, but I highly doubt I installed it to that location. Past this Windows reinstall I've tested my audio levels in Discord. I've been able to observe some high pitched whining in the input sensitivity bar (I believe it wasn't background noise being picked up) and also heard it through mic playback tests (again, through Discord). I also tried unplugging my mixer, microphone, and headset to see if the noise was introduced from those sources. The only one that seems to help any was unplugging my headphones, until I realized why I couldn't hear the whining anymore.
I'm running:
berringer Xenyx Q502 USB mixer
A Shure XM58 mic
Some hand me down computer speakers that hook into the rear audio jack
and a Sennheiser headphones currently plugged into the optical
I have two cats, it's entirely possible that a cable may have minor bites, but I'm unsure that would introduce a whine. (again, not an audio guy)
My cable management also has all of these cables running close together, after reading a few other threads I will likely try to isolate the mixer usb to pc run just in case.
Thanks for any help, I'll try to respond and get an audio recording of the issue asap.

Your mixer has a built in compressor, are you using that feature? What is the compression knob set to?
If you plug your headphones into the mixer, do you hear the whine?  how about if you unplug the mic with the headphones in the mixer?
